# Publishing Serenity reports in e-mail

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

When I send serenity report index.html from my machine to another person, the report does not open properly and clickable links in the report don't work. But when I zip entire serenity folder and send it across in the e-mail the report opens properly. has anybody else faced this issue?Can someone tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: what you mean by sending index.html have you just sent only the .html file. I dont think so. Anyway when you zip that file all of it necessary css and image file are being with it. So only that file has been shown well when sending on Zip.

Comment: Thanks Selva for your response. Please correct me if I understood wrong, I should send the folders : CSS and Images along with the index.html in e-mail and the person who ever is opening the index.html should be able to view the report properly?

Comment: yes since to view the complete HTML it requires the css and the images hence you need to send the wholde folder in a zip file.